# Different line-height in Firefox and Chrome when using text-shadow

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, css

For some reason, Firefox and Chrome render line-height differently when using text-shadow.

CSS:

```css
#tracker {
    width:200px;
    color:#999;
    font:normal 12px Verdana,sans-serif;/* Swapped out Arial with Verdana */
}

#tracker ol {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style: none;
}

#tracker li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 6px;
    padding: 0;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 13px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#tracker li.current {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #033e69;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #13699e;
    border: 1px solid #369;
}
#tracker li span{display:none;}
#step1:before{content:"1"}
#step2:before{content:"2"}
#step3:before{content:"3"}
#step4:before{content:"4"}​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tracker">
    <span class="steps">Steps <span id="current-step">1</span> of 4</span>
    <ol>
        <li id="step1" class="current"><span>Sender</span></li>
        <li id="step2" class="future"><span>Recipient</span></li>
        <li id="step3" class="future"><span>Delivery info</span></li>
        <li id="step4" class="future"><span>Line items</span></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

When the text-shadow is below the text (positive numbers) it presses the text up.

[image: Tracker-webkit-firefox]

Shouldn't the text be the same no matter where the shadow is rendered? (as shown in FF and IE?)

The only work-around I have found is to increase the line-height (from 13px to 15px) when shadow is below (using positive numbers), but then it screws it up for non-webkit browsers (Firefox and IE).

[Demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/qU5dc/17/)... Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I figured it out and have updated my code. It was a font issue. I was using Arial but when I changed it to Verdana the problem was solved. Very strange!

**[The solution!](http://jsfiddle.net/qU5dc/16/)** :)

Comment: please avoid updating your question, but instead add an answer to depict the solution. revert the edit to previous state so problem can be seen again with the provided code.

Comment: Since I have less than 100 reputation, the system wouldn't let me submit an answer for eight hours. I have now submitted an answer (below) but it won't let me accept it as a solution for another six hours. The problem is still in my OP, linked to as "Demo of the problem" and I commented in the code what was changed (the font, from Arial to Verdana). Isn't that enough?

Comment: more than enough, the community thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Arial and Helvetica fonts when rendered at sizes below 10px. Changing the font to Verdana fixes the problem.

The only part of the code I had to change was the following declaration in the CSS:

```css
#tracker { 
    /* from this...
    font:normal 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;*/ 
    /* to this...*/
    font: normal 12px Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

**[The solution!](http://jsfiddle.net/qU5dc/16/)** :)

**Alternatively**,
It also works if you use larger font-sizes for Arial or Helvetica, **[as demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/qU5dc/18/)**.
(But then you need to increase the height & width of the step-circles from 13px to 14px.)

Here's the CSS for the larger font version, using Arial or Helvetica:

```css
#tracker { 
    /* this has changed */
    font: normal 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    /* the rest is the same as before */
    width: 200px;
    color: #999;
}

#tracker ol {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style: none;
}

#tracker li { 
    /* these were changed */
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    font-size: 11px;
    /* the rest is the same as before */
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 6px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.45em;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#tracker li.current {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px #033e69;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #13699e;
    border: 1px solid #369;
}

#tracker li span {
    display: none;
}

#step1:before {
    content: "1"
}

#step2:before {
    content: "2"
}

#step3:before {
    content: "3"
}

#step4:before {
    content: "4"
}
​
```

Answer (score 23):

Specifying the line height in text-relative units will provide consistent behavior across rendering engines.

Simply calculate the container-height to text-height relation:

> 13 / 9 = 1.444~

... and apply that to the relevant rule in the CSS:

```css
#tracker li {
    line-height: 1.444;
}
```

**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qU5dc/40/)**

Comment: Crap. I spoke to soon. It was brilliant, but unfortunately it hasn't solved the problem for me (even though I see it works on jsFiddle). Must be something else in my css that is causing the problem...

Comment: I added more to the css in your [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qU5dc/8/) to represent how I have the code.

Comment: Figured it out and updated my code above, it was a font issue (Arial is buggy but Verdana works fine), possibly due to the small size?

Comment: Here is **[a demo using the exact code](http://jsfiddle.net/qU5dc/17/)** so you can see the problem, and how using EM's doesn't solve it. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: oh crapidy crap... well glad to see you solved it regardless, please add an answer to your question for the benefit of others encountering this issue.