# text flow and css3 zoom property

Tags: html, css, zooming, scale

I have a div containing text. In editmode this div is zoomed out to roughly 0.9 using css to fit in my admin interface.
In presentation mode it is however not zoomed out, and there - loand behold - the text flows totally different. Line feeds are in totally different places.

Is there a way around this or will I just have to give up on zooming out during editing?

Look in bottom right corner on these pics... First the scaled version in editmode, then the full-size, unscaled, unzoomed version for presentation mode.

[image: scaled]

[image: full size]

Comment: you need to use fixed height?

Comment: Yup, it's an editor for content where the user can resize and move text areas to exact dimensions and positions.

Comment: have you tried overflow: scroll or overflow: auto?

Comment: It's overflow hidden on all text areas. The example might be a bit misguiding, the blue area behind the text is actually its own object, a text area with no text in it, with background set to blue, positioned behind the text area with the text :-) why? Because I use opacity on the background color but don't want the text dimmed.

Comment: change the background textarea to a div with background: rgba(red, green, blue, value-of-opacity) and inside it the textarea. the rgba opacity dont spread the effect to its child elements

Comment: Thanks, that's agood point. However that's not what the basic question is about =) The basic problem is not that I want to keep my two objects the same size, the problem is that if the user determines that a certain textarea it to be of width 100px and height 200px, and the users sees in the preview that all text fits inside that window (while preview area being zoomed to 0.9), it is unacceptable that the text, when this area is zoomed up to 1.0, flows ove an entirely different area, requiring more space as the images portray...

Comment: it would be a lot easier to help if you could provide a sample code or perhaps a jsfiddle. Also do what toping suggested giving the divs a fixed width. Also try fiddling with these properties `word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word` for your textbox/divs.

Comment: At least in Chrome, there is a bug with the font rendering in a zoomed div. You can see that in fiddled that I provided in my answer. For instance, the line height is different. At first I thought that it could be a problem about rounding the font-size (that is, for a font-size of 12px * 0.9 -> 11px instead of 10.8ox) but I tried with different font sizes and no longer think that this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I have reproduced your issue at 100%; but I have prepared a similar layout, and found the same problem than you in Chrome.

But changing zoom to

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
-ms-transform: scale(0.9);
transform: scale(0.9);
```

solved the problem in Chrome.

In IE10, the problem didn't show.

Haven't tried others browsers, though.

If suport for IE 8 is required I would try :

```
#transformedObject {

/* IE8+ - must be on one line, unfortunately */ 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.9, M12=0, M21=0, M22=0.9, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
```

This taken from [useragentman web](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/), I haven't tried it

I see that my previous comment was poorly explained: In my tests in IE10, both the zoom and the transform worked well. I don't know if I have reproduced the problem exactly, so I don't know if I have solved it; but I least looks like it's safe to do the change.

See it in test:

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/3RxG7/embedded/result/)

When you check the checkbox, the width of the divs will grow, just to see different adjusts to the layout. The divs are: original, transformed (green) zoomed (red) and both transformed and zoomed overlayed to see the difference. At least in IE 10, both transformed and zoomed are equivalents to the original.

Comment: Ok, are you saying to skip zoom all together or do I still need that for the zoom effect in internet Explorer? If so, how will i tell the browser to use the rule that works with IT and for example not have chrome go on zoom which is there for explorer... Hope you understood the question, got a little messy there :-)

Comment: Do you need support for IE 8 ?  If that is not the case, I would skip zoom altogether and use transform. If yes, I would try -ms-filter. See updated answer

Comment: Now it works perfectly in chrome. The same object looks very different though in chrome and firefox =( line breaks are in the exact same places, but it appears that either the letter height or line space is different (in spite of line-height being fixed at 1.5em)...

Comment: Hmm... if I set line-height to a pixel value it looks the exact same... so the two browsers calculate line-height sizes expressed in EM differently... interesting. Well, that will be a bit of a hassle for me but doable =)

Comment: I just learned from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665541/different-line-height-in-firefox-and-chrome-when-using-text-shadow (and positively confirmed on my code) that this line-height issue between chrome and firefox only applies for font sizes about 10px and below, and only on some fonts, not all. Still.. =)

Answer (score 1):

In Web pages you have no proper text-flow control. Mainly this is because different browsers on different platform render the font glyphs differently. The tracking of your text will differ as well. So if you optimize your text to look awesome on your own browser, it might suck on a different one. So say goodby to pixel exact text representation in web browsers. It's a forlorn hope.

P.S.:
Don't use `text-align: justify` on web pages. It really sucks.