# Line height being represented differently on browsers

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome

I have a header section and a subsequent nav section, and the nav section displays fine in terms on height on what im developing on (MacBook Pro Retina) however when I try viewing the site on a windows machine (both in chrome) the apparent line height is completely different, I tried taking the line height property out and it doesn't help:
[image: Display on the Mac in Chrome]

[image: Display on windows Chrome]

CSS:

```
.nav {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 
             0px 14px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
             0px 10px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
             0px 34px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.nav li {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav a { color: rgba(255,255,255,.55); transition: .3s ease; -webkit-transition: .3s ease;} .nav a:hover { color: white; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #b2a98f,
             0px 14px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
             0px 10px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
             0px 34px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
} 
.nav-white { color: white !important; text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #b2a98f,
             0px 14px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
             0px 10px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
             0px 34px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
         /*text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);*/
}

.header-text {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
/*  border-bottom: 5px solid white; underline that header!*/
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-shadow: 0px 3px 0px #b2a98f,
             0px 14px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),
             0px 18px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
             0px 34px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}


.header-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 420px;
    background-color: #FE5B35;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

I'm not sure whether it's to do with the mac's pixel density but I haven't had an issue like this in the past when developing; things have matching fairly nice in the past.
**EDIT:**
There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665541/different-line-height-in-firefox-and-chrome-when-using-text-shadow) which says it is to do with the text shadow, and it's solved by altering the font, I do not wish to alter the font. Is there a work around?

HTML:

```
<span class='header-text'>EVERYTHING ROB</span>
                    <div class='nav'>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href='portfolio/' class='portfolio-nav'>Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="code-snippets" class='code-snippets-nav'>Code Snippets</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact-me" class='contact-me-nav'>Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Comment: If you fiddled something up or pasted the html, that would help us.

Comment: Please show either a live sample of the site or a Jsfiddle.

Comment: The rendering of the code in the question is completely different from the screen shots. Please provide code that actually reproduces the problem and describe, referring to directly observable things, what the problem is. (Line height, for example, is not directly observable – you cannot see whether some vertical spacing is caused by it, or by padding, or by margin, or by something else.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use CSS reset. This makes sure that the size and spacing is always the same independent the browser.
See more: [About CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)

Put it before all your CSS code:

```
* {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border: 0;
   list-style:none;
   vertical-align:baseline;
   line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: CSS Resets tend to cause more problems than they solve. You should find the *specific* properties that cause problems, and set them (to zero or something else).

Comment: I think the specific propertie will resolve his problem is line-height. Maybe: *{line-height: 1;} before all code will solve.